# how to set xml attribute value change if xml element name is same

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have the following XML file:

```
<root>
  <SignUp user_id = 'joseph' image = 'myByk.jpg' />
  <SignUp user_id = 'jack' image = 'myCar.jpg' />  
  <SignUp user_id = 'lamp' image = 'myhome.jpg' />
</root>
```

Within this file I want to get the `SignUp` element with the `user_id` "`jack`", and change its `image` attribute.

I have tried the following PHP code:

```
<?php
  $dom = new DomDocument();
  $dom->load('data_out.xml');
  $xp = new DomXPath($dom);
  $res = $xp->query("//*[@user_id = 'jack']");
  $xp->SignUp->attributes()->image = "my School.jpg";
  $dom->save('data_out.xml');
?>
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in the [query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) you are going by attribute you can have multiple result elements so it is wrapped in a list of some sort ([dom node list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php)).

Here is what I am thinking (untested):

```
<?php
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->load('data_out.xml');
    $xp = new DomXPath($dom);
    $res = $xp->query("//*[@user_id = 'jack']");
    $res->item(0)->setAttribute("image", "my School.jpg");
    $dom->save('data_out.xml');
?>
```

---

Similar code successfully tested in a [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/):

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML(
    "<root>
        <SignUp user_id = 'joseph' image = 'myByk.jpg' />
        <SignUp user_id = 'jack' image = 'myCar.jpg' />  
        <SignUp user_id = 'lamp' image = 'myhome.jpg' />
    </root>"
);
$xp = new DomXPath($dom);
$res = $xp->query("//*[@user_id = 'jack']");
$res->item(0)->setAttribute("image", "my School.jpg");
$ret =  $dom->saveXML();
echo $ret;
```

returns

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <SignUp user_id="joseph" image="myByk.jpg"/>
    <SignUp user_id="jack" image="my School.jpg"/>  
    <SignUp user_id="lamp" image="myhome.jpg"/>
</root>
```

Comment: this return error on line 6 `Call to undefined method DOMXPath::item()`

Comment: right, should be fixed now, was dereferencing the wrong variable.

Comment: yeh thats work but i am not use xml as a string what for this?

Comment: @jackxml, Also note that the attributes property that you tried to set in your original code is _readonly_: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php

Comment: @7stud I think that idea originates from [SimpleXMLElement](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) jack is trying to access attributes as a method, for DomNode it's a member.

Answer (score 1):

Then perhaps the op should consider using SimpleXML:

```
if ($root = simplexml_load_file('xml.xml') ) 
{
    //access attributes like an array:
    echo $root->SignUp[0]["user_id"] . "\n";  

    $target_elements = $root->xpath("//*[@user_id = 'jack']");
    $target_elements[0]["image"] = "mySchool.jpg";
    $root->asXML('datat_out.xml');

}
```

Note that to change an attribute, you don't have to use the cumbersome:

```
$target_attr = "image";
$target_elements[0]->attributes()->$target_attr = "hello";
```